# Finding the expected value and variance for $Y_n^{(c)}$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

I am to find all $\beta > 0$ such that the following series converges:
$$\sum \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{- \beta} \big(X_n - E(X_n) \big). \tag{1}$$
$X_n$ is a random variable with exponential distribution with $\alpha$ parameter $(\alpha > 0)$.

Let's define:
$$Y_n = n^{- \beta} \big(X_n - E(X_n) \big).$$
It's easy to calculate that:

1. $E(Y_n) = 0,$
2. $Var(Y_n) = \frac{n^{-2 \beta}}{\alpha^2}.$

From [Kolmogorov's two series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem) we can easily justify that for $\beta > \frac{1}{2}$ $(1)$ converges.

---

Now I would like to use [Kolmogorov's three series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) to check whether $(1)$ converges for $\beta \le \frac{1}{2}$.

Let's consider:
$$Y_n^{(c)} = \begin{cases} Y_n, \text{     for       } |Y_n|  \le c\\0, \text{   else}\end{cases}$$
My question is how can I find:

1. $E(Y_n^{(c)})$,
2. $Var(Y_n^{(c)})$?

Comment: One does not need exact formulas for $E(Y_n^{(c)})$ and $Var(Y_n^{(c)})$ but only their equivalents when $n\to\infty$. And these are easy...

Comment: @Did What do you mean by equivalents?\

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis